# определить количество слагаемых Ряда Маклорена

Tags: c++

[image]

Определить, сколько слагаемых ряда Маклорена потребуется, чтобы вычислить значение функции е^x с заданной точностью эпсилон

Нужно искать сумму ряда, пока она не станет в промежут
Exp(x) - eps < sum < exp(x) + eps, но не могу понять как это в виде кода записать

Comment: Уже попытались что-то написать? Покажете попытку?

Comment: Какое-то условие недосказанное. Ну хорошо, цикл написать можно, но я не совсем понял с чем его сравнивать. Может быть с каким-то библиотечным вызовом?

Comment: @viktoria2 прошу вас выбрать правильный ответ среди 3-х, это поможет тем у кого возникнет похожий вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте 4 переменные:

1. - Первая, пусть будет вещественным числом `sum`
   - Очевидно думаю для чего она
2. - Вторая, целочисленное число например `count`
   - Она будет отвечать за кол-во слагаемых
3. - Третья переменная будет число целочисленного типа `pow_x`
   - Будет в роли числителя, т.е. степень `x`
4. - И четвертая так же целочисленная переменная `fact`
   - Будет отвечать за знаменатель, т.е. факториал

Начальные значения переменных будут равны `1` т.к. мы возьмем сразу первое слагаемое (это 1).

Далее пишите цикл `do ... while` с условием, который вы написали в вопросе, но обратным (то есть чтобы пока сумма не входит в промежуток `[exp(x) - eps; exp(x) + eps]`)

Ну а далее каждую итерацию:

1. Умножаете `pow_x` на `x`
2. `fact` умножаете на `count` (можно было переменную отдельную сделать для понимания, но ...)
3. Добавляете к сумме, частное числителя и знаменателя.
4. Увеличиваете `count` на единицу

Если все правильно, то при `x = 1, eps = 1e-7` вы должны получить на выходе 11 слагаемых.

Никогда так не делал, но ниже я выложу ссылку на код, который полностью объяснен выше. Делаю это для того чтобы, если вы попробуете, но у вас не будет получатся, то вы могли посмотреть пример реализации. Я обижусь если вы просто скопируете код. А вот и [код](https://ideone.com/rYF7ku). Удачи! :)

Answer (score 0):

Код работает для e^2, e^3, но когда вы вызываете для e^5, происходит переполнение разрядной сетки и цикл итерируется бесконечно, но думаю этого достаточно.

```
#include <math>
#include <iostream>

double getEpsilon(std::uint32_t order) {
    return std::pow(10.0, -static_cast<double>(order));
}

std::vector<int> already_calculated_factorials = { 1, 1 };

std::uint32_t factorial(std::uint32_t number) {
    if (number < already_calculated_factorials.size()) {
        return already_calculated_factorials.at(number);
    }
 
    if (number == already_calculated_factorials.size()) {
        const auto last_fact = already_calculated_factorials.back();
        already_calculated_factorials.emplace_back(number * last_fact);
        return already_calculated_factorials.back();
    }

    while (already_calculated_factorials.size() < number) {
        const auto curr_num = already_calculated_factorials.size();
        const auto last_fact = already_calculated_factorials.back();
        already_calculated_factorials.emplace_back(curr_num * last_fact);
    }

    return already_calculated_factorials.back();
}

double calculateExponenta(double x, double epsilon) {
    double macloren_sum = 0;
    std::uint32_t number_of_members = 0;

    const auto std_exp_value = std::exp(x);

    while (std::abs(macloren_sum - std_exp_value) >= epsilon) {
        macloren_sum += std::pow(x, static_cast<double>(number_of_members)) / factorial(number_of_members);

        number_of_members++;
    }

    return macloren_sum;
}

int main() {
    calculateExponenta(2, getEpsilon(1));
    return 0;
}
```

Пояснения по коду

1. Факториал вычисляется на основе уже предыдущих вычислений дабы не повторять лишние итерации
2. У нас есть значение "истино верного" значения библиотечной функции `std_exp_value = std::exp(x);`
3. У нас есть сумма ряда Маклорена `macloren_sum`. В цикле мы производим суммирование.
   `std::pow(x, static_cast<double>(number_of_members)) / factorial(number_of_members);` соответствует формуле x^n/n!

Comment: 1) На этом сайте не очень красиво просто скидывать код, отвечая на вопросы где просто условие. 2) Выглядит как код библиотеки, какой нибудь. Я думаю автору будет сложно понять такой код. 3) Не думаю что хорошая идея каждый раз по новой находить факториал числа, и степень `x`. 4) С чего вы взяли что ошибка в цикле?

Comment: 1. Да, не прав тут 2. Да тут ничего библиотечного. 3. Исправил на вариант получше

Answer (score 0):

Странно определять количество нужных слагаемых сравнивая частичную сумму со значением функции. Если мы умеем вычислять функцию точно, зачем возиться с рядом?

В случае ряда Маклорена/Тейлора можно оценить [остаточный член в форме Лагранжа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0). Формула для нашего конкретного ряда упрощается до

```
x >= 0: R(n, x) <= 2*L(n, x)*S(n, x) / (1 - L(n, x)^2), если L(n, x) < 1
x <  0: R(n, x) <= L(n, x)
где
a(n, x) = x^n / n! - член ряда Маклорена, 
L(n, x) = |a(n + 1, x)| - абсолютная величина следующего члена ряда Маклорена,
S(n, x) = sum(a(i, x) | 0 <= i <= n)) - частичная сумма ряда Маклорена,
R(n, x) = |e^x - S(n, x)| - остаточный член, ошибка, невязка,
                            разница между частичной суммой и самой фунцией.
```

С помощью этих формул мы может оценить размер частичной суммы не вычисляя саму функцию:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra maclaurin_exp.cpp

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

void approximate(double eps, double x, int &sn, double &sum) {
    double s = 0;
    double a = 1;
    for (int n = 0; ; ++n) {
        s += a;
        a *= x / (n + 1);
        double l = std::abs(a);
        if (x >= 0) {
            if (l < 1 && 2 * l * s / (1 - l * l) <= eps) {
                sn = n;
                sum = s;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (l <= eps) {
                sn = n;
                sum = s;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);

    while (true) {
        double eps;
        std::cout << "\neps: ";
        if (!(std::cin >> eps)) {
            break;
        }

        double x;
        std::cout << "x: ";
        if (!(std::cin >> x)) {
            break;
        }

        int n;
        double y;
        approximate(eps, x, n, y);
        double error = std::abs(std::exp(x) - y);
        std::cout
            << "eps = " << eps
            << ", x = " << x
            << ", n = " << n
            << ", y = " << y
            << ", error " << error << ' ' << ((error < eps) ? "OK" : "ERROR")
            << '\n';
    }
}
```

Пример:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra maclaurin_exp.cpp && ./a.out

eps: 0.0001    
x: 0.1
eps = 0.0001, x = 0.10000000000000001, n = 3, y = 1.1051666666666666, error 4.2514089810818945e-06 OK

eps: 0.0001
x: 1
eps = 0.0001, x = 1, n = 8, y = 2.71827876984127, error 3.0586177750535626e-06 OK

eps: 0.0001
x: 10
eps = 0.0001, x = 10, n = 41, y = 22026.465794805794, error 9.2404661700129509e-10 OK

eps: 0.0001
x: 0   
eps = 0.0001, x = 0, n = 0, y = 1, error 0 OK

eps: 0.0001
x: -0.1
eps = 0.0001, x = -0.10000000000000001, n = 3, y = 0.90483333333333338, error 4.0847026261392472e-06 OK

eps: 0.0001
x: -1
eps = 0.0001, x = -1, n = 7, y = 0.36785714285714288, error 2.2298314299451505e-05 OK

eps: 0.0001
x: -10
eps = 0.0001, x = -10, n = 33, y = 1.9092257563066713e-05, error 2.6307672199418141e-05 OK
```